# Traveling via a third country

Tags: passports, passport-stamps

I've read an answer about traveling via a third country in case dual citizenship might not to be OK, and I don't know whether it is technically possible. I'm a citizen of Germany and Saudi Arabia, and I want to travel via UAE. Once I arrive in Saudi Arabia, I'll try to enter with KSA pass but a Saudi official may see from passport that I live in Germany, and in that point is there a risk that he may ask me for German residence permit or stamps or a visa? How can I possibly tackle this situation?

Comment: this will not be answerable without naming all the countries involved.

Comment: am I right that your concern is "you have passport A so in you come - hey, wait, I see in your A passport that you live in B, so you had better have a visa because B people need a visa!" that's not a thing.

Comment: And more generally I'm asking how someone might travel via a third country. I've read an answer, but I haven't found it clear though.

Comment: The countries I'm a citizen of require a visa to each other's citizens

Comment: No, the issue is that the authorities of a country might ask me the permanent residence of the country I'm living in, which I'm also a citizen of, and if I say to them that I'm a citizen of that country too, then...

Comment: then what? that's what needs to be in the question, and it won't be answerable unless the countries are specifically named.

Comment: Germany and KSA

Comment: Regarding the third country, let's say that I want to transit in the UAE. What can I do then?

Comment: It seems that you're worried that KSA will see that you live in Germany but you do not have German stamps or visas in your passport, nor a German residence permit -- or vice versa.  is that correct?  You are right that traveling via a third country will not help with this.  The trick is to try not to let the country where you don't live know that you live in the other country.

Comment: if I had KSA residence in Saudi passport then it would have been a lot easier.

Comment: Yes, thhat's it. That way and viceversa. both of them.

Comment: Anyway, how can I travel in case I manage to get a Saudi residence in Saudi passport?

Answer (score 1):

> a Saudi official may see from passport that I live in Germany

**How would he see that?**  You're a German citizen, you don't need visas or anything, so there should be nothing in the Saudi passport that links you to Germany.

The main exception here is if you have **renewed your Saudi passport in Germany**, in which case this may be stated in the passport and lead to questions.  This is why it's generally advisable for secret dual citizens to renew their passport in their home country.

> Is there a risk that he may ask me for German residence permit or
>   stamps or a visa?

**Yes**, there is always a risk, since at the end of the day what you're doing is against Saudi law.  The risk is low if you arrive via a third country and there's nothing obviously linking you to your second country of citizenship, but Immigration officers can ask anything they like and a question like "Where have you been for the last two years?" can quickly lead you to thin ice.